# iOS Detecting UISwipeGestureRecognizer with two directions under one pressing

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, cocoa-touch, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I'm trying to detecting a two finger swipe touch and use it like the touch board in Mac(two finger up and two finger down listening) and the code like;

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeUpTwoFinger = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeTwoFinger:)];
swipeUpTwoFinger.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
swipeUpTwoFinger.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeUpTwoFinger];

UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeDownTwoFinger = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSwipeTwoFinger:)];
swipeDownTwoFinger.numberOfTouchesRequired = 2;
swipeDownTwoFinger.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown;
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeDownTwoFinger];


-(void)handleSwipeTwoFinger:(UISwipeGestureRecognizer *)swipeGestureRecognizer
{
    if (swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp) {
        NSLog(@"handleSwipeUpTwoFinger");
    }
    else if (swipeGestureRecognizer.direction == UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionDown) {
        NSLog(@"handleSwipeDownTwoFinger");
    }
}
```

**The Problem is**

I could get a Up or Down Swipe when I touch,but just one event whatever I do the Up Down swipe under one pressing.

What I want is like the touch board in Mac,when I swipe up it listened and without leaving the board swipe down it could listened too.

**The Question is**

How could I do this with UISwipeGestureRecognizer?
Or it have limitation couldn't do what I want should I do it with UIPanGestureRecognizer or listening various touch event do logic with myself? or any other implementation ? any demo?

any suggestions would be appreciated :)

Comment: Swipe gestures only recognize a single direction. What you want is a pan gesture

Comment: @markedwardmurray yes I find out swipe gesture is **discrete gesture** :(... so I'm trying to use Pan gesture to implement it by myself